# Creating a script for approve workflow in Google Forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, form-submit

I am trying to develop an approval workflow for time requested off via google form. An add-on would solve this no problem but my company is weird about that stuff so I was trying to generate a script to perform this function. I'm getting so many errors in my doGet function I"m just about to give up.

I've tried googling each individual error to see how I can fix it. I've tried seeing if there is a script that someone has already done but no luck. What I want is for the person to submit their request off form. An email be sent to the supervisor with a link to approve/deny the request then an email sent back to the original requester with their results.

I forgot to add. This is the script I am plugging in to the google sheet that is attached to the google form not the form itself. The error that I seem to keep getting is "TypeError: Cannot read property "approval" from undefined"

```js
function sendemail(e) {

  var email = e.values[1];
  var supervisoremail = e.values[2];
  var begindateabsent = e.values[3];
  var enddateabsent = e.values[4];

  var url =
    'https://script.google.com/a/mesd.k12.or.us/macros/s/AKfycbwvm63UG8X9Wqdkt7yxUFKhvMXu58yvbeY2udJVJKmheIuagQlB/exec';

  var approve = url + '&approval=true' + '&reply=' + email;
  var deny = url + '&approval=false' + '&reply=' + email;

  var html = "<body>" +
    "<h2>Please review/<h2><br />" +
    begindateabsent + ": " + enddateabsent + "<br />" +
    "<a href=" + approve + ">Approve</a><br />" +
    "<a href=" + deny ? ">Deny</a><br />" +
    "</body>" :
    MailApp.sendEmail("lparga@mesd.k12.or.us", "Approval request", "What no html?", { htmlBody: html });
}

function doGet(e) {
  var answer = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ?'Your request has been approved' : "Your request has been denied";

  MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Your leave request",
    "Your supervisor said: " + answer);

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createHTML('<h2>An email was sent to ' + e.parameter.reply + 'saying: ' + answer + '</h2 > '));
  return app;
}
```

current error says my reply parameter on my `doGet` function is not defined.

Comment: Welcome. The UiApp method is deprecated instead you could use HTML Service. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web.

Comment: Are you use that `e.values[1]` is returning a valid email address? Also check typos around `deny` ("`replay`", "`? ... :`")

Comment: Welcome. "reply parameter... is not defined." That does seem rather clear. I suggest you grab the Event objects that are being returned and trouble-shoot from there. `JSON.stringify(e);` is the way to go and there's an example in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Comment: use ? to start query parameter '?&approval=true'

Answer (score 0):

For accessing an element via a GET petition in Google Apps Script you may use the [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation). This is, using `e.reply` instead of `e.parameter.reply`.

On the other hand, we need to rewrite the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) syntax to make it run. Your final code should look something similar to this:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var answer = (typeof e.approval == 'true' ? 'Your request has been approved' : "Your request has been denied");
    MailApp.sendEmail(e.reply, "Your leave request", "Your supervisor said: " + answer);
    var app = UiApp.createApplication(); // DEPRECATED
    app.add(app.createHTML('<h2>An email was sent to ' + e.reply + 'saying: ' + answer + '</h2 > '));
}
```

I hope that this is useful for you. Please, don't hesitate to offer us more information for further help.

Comment: If `doGet` was called with URL parameters (e.g. https://.../exec?reply=foo), then `e.parameter.reply` is correct.  Only if `doGet` was called in some other context (e.g. `google.script.run`) would `e.reply` be available.  Since the url is built with a query string, it looks like `e.parameter.reply` is correct.  Also consider deleting [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) as it will never return the string `'true'`.

Comment: Thank you but I still get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property "approval" from undefined." when I try to run the function. Which has been the main error I have been encountering. I changed the script to what you recommended and deleted 'typeof' but still get that error in line 25 so I begin the code with "var answer = (e.approval==true and so on...

Answer (score 0):

> The error that I seem to keep getting is "TypeError: Cannot read property "approval" from undefined"

This error occurs because the URL being created by the code doesn't include `?`. This character is required to show where the query string part of the URL starts.

Replace

```
var approve = url + '&approval=true' + '&reply=' + email;
var deny = url + '&approval=false' + '&reply=' + email;
```

by

```
var approve = url + '?approval=true' + '&reply=' + email;
var deny = url + '?approval=false' + '&reply=' + email;
```

Another problem on the code is the use of UiApp (because it was deprecated and retired). Instead you should use the HTML Service.

References

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Answer (score -1):

I designed a solution with two different forms and one google sheet with two sheet for the forms. the first one form for the registration of information and the second one for approval, maybe you could use it:

```
 function sendEmail() {
  Logger.log("[METHOD] sendEmail");


  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // ingresa a la planilla
  var row = values.getLastRow();  
  var fecha = values.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  var email = values.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var div = values.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  var section = values.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
  var id = values.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
  var nom = values.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  var tipo = values.getRange(row, 8).getValue(); 
  var val_tipo = values.getRange(row, 9).getValue();
  var origen = values.getRange(row, 10).getValue();
  var riesgo = values.getRange(row, 11).getValue();
  var oport = values.getRange(row, 12).getValue();
  var conform = values.getRange(row, 13).getValue();
  var correo_owner = values.getRange(row, 14).getValue();
  var emailRecipients = correo_owner;
  var urlform = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/(put here de ID's form)/viewform?formkey=unique_number&entry_(put here the  entry number of to prefill form)="+id+"&entry_(put here the  entry number of to prefill form)="+val_tipo+"&entry_(put here the  entry number of to prefill form)="+email;

  var emailSubject = "Ingreso de registro de no conformidad/oportunidad de mejora n° "+id+" por " + email ;

  // Cuerpo del correo
  var emailBody = "<h3>Ingreso de registro reportado por "+nom+":</h3><hr /> \
  <p> \
  <h3 style='line-height:70%'>Ingreso de No conformidad/oportunidad de mejora <br /> 
  \
  <span style='font-size:50%'>("+fecha+")</span></h3> \
  </p><hr /> \ <p> \
  <strong>Tipo de reporte:</strong><br /> \
  "+tipo+" \
  </p>\ <p> \
  <strong>Origen de Hallazgo:</strong><br /> \
  "+origen+" \
   </p> <p> \
   <strong>Descripción de 'No conformidad':</strong><br /> \
   "+conform+" \
   </p> \ <p> \
   <strong>Descripción de Oportunidad de Mejora:</strong><br /> \
   "+oport+" \
   </p>\ <p> \
   <strong>División:</strong><br /> \
   "+div+" \
   </p>\ <p> \
   <strong>Sección:</strong><br /> \
   "+section+" \
   </p>\ <p> \
   <strong>Favor aprobar, rechazar o derivar el requerimiento en el siguiente link: 
   </strong><br />\
   "+urlform+"\
   </p>"   ;

   MailApp.sendEmail({
   to: emailRecipients,
   cc: "mail1"+","+"mail2",// + "mail3",
   subject: emailSubject,
   htmlBody: emailBody
   });
```